# Random cut forest anomaly detection on multi variant time series data

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, anomaly-detection

I have sensor data coming from equipment with times series along with many attributes,

I have used RCF algorithm to detect anomalies.
Now the challenge is,how to to convince the end user whether it is really anomaly or not.
Just want to know which attribute is contributing to anomaly.

Is there any best way to convince end user whether it is really anomaly or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to run the RCF model and to get the explanation for the anomaly is to use the version of RCF in Kinesis Analytics (KA). Here is a link to the documentation of how to run from the KA documentations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/sqlref/sqlrf-random-cut-forest-with-explanation.html

Kinesis is taking care both for the training of the model, the inference after the initial training and for the attribution and explanation of the variables.

[image: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/sqlref/images/anomaly_results.png]

Comment: Hi Guy, thanks a lot for your valuable response.i already have the end point with me from the hyper parameter tuning job.is there anyway to do the attribution with rcf explanation concept from same end point.

Comment: The current RCF algorithm in SageMaker didn't implement the attribution functionality that you can find in KA, AFAIK. Therefore, you can't get it from the endpoint in the SageMaker (SM) service.

Comment: Hi Guy, thanks lot for your confirmation.in our case,data is located in S3 location and could not afford Kinesis  stream as there are several  models.you have mentioned about KA and AFAIK,could you please elobrate more on this,please let me if you have any better technique for attribution

Comment: @Anantha, I apologize for the confusion of using acronyms, KA = "Kinesis Analytics", and AFAIK - "As Far As I Know", and are not names of other libraries.